# VC C++ DLL files not produced in expected folder for use with VBA

Tags: c++, excel, debugging, vba, dll

I have just watched a video tutorial on how to set up a C++ DLL file to call in Excel VBA. I'm just doing a simple one to start off with. So I open a new win32 project and chose DLL and empty project in the application wizard and proceed. Then I make a .cpp file and a .def file as follows:

square.cpp file:

```
double __stdcall square(double & x)
{
          return x*x;
}
```

defFile.def:

```
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS
square
```

Then to project properties -> Linker -> input-> Module Definition File: defFile.def

and then I compile.

Now, a .dll file should appear in the project Debug folder, but it doesn't. Any idea's whats wrong?

P.S. I'm fairly new to programming so try and go easy on the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, VC++ uses two folders named Debug when you compile a project, one at the solution's directory and the other in the project's directory.

First you should check if there were any errors during the compilation. If it's succeeded, then you can proceed to check the folder named Debug in your **solution** path.

You can go there just by right-clicking in `Solution 'square' (1 project)` in the Solution Explorer, and selecting `Open folder in Windows Explorer`. Then going into the first folder name Debug. By default, that's where VC++ stores the final executable. The other Debug folder, located in the project's directory is just for intermediary files.

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

I cannot find this 'open folder in windows explorer' option when i right click "Solution 'square' (1 project)" though. Any help with this would be great. edit: actually now there is a .dll file in the debug folder. I think the problem was I was only compiling the function rather than compiling the whole project. Thanks for the help.